# Switching images with a delay

Tags: android, loops, delay, android-image

I want my app to switch two images with a delay of, let's say, 3 seconds. This is my former code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ImageView image = (ImageView)      
 findViewById(R.id.imgView_dice0);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_6);      
        }
    }, 3000);
}
....
```

This works for switching the image one time. I tried putting the image-changing in two methods (and replacing `R.drawable.dice_6` with `R.drawable.dice_1`) which are called with a delay, surrounded by a loop. That doesn't work, the app only shows one and the same dice all the time.
What should I do?

Comment: 3 secs -> Change image -> Wait other 3 seconds -> Change again. That's what you want to do?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Show dice1, wait 3 seconds, show dice6, wait 3 seconds, show dice1...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should restart your `Handler.postDelayed` inside the runnable to make it work.

Something like:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    private boolean useDiceOne;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView_dice0);
        if (!useDiceOne) {
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_6);
        } else {
         image.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_1);
        }
        useDiceOne = !useDiceOne;
        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);      
    }
 }, 3000);
```

`useDiceOne` will be used to change the image between `dice_1` and `dice_6`
p.s cache the `ImageView`.

To make it more flexible (stop it when you want, etc.) you could save the handler reference (and runnable reference too) somewhere and use removeCallbacks

Comment: P.S.: For the sake of accurateness: substitude "timeForOne" for "useDiceOne" :)

Comment: Done, i changed the name because "timeForOne" looks very bad :)